# How to browse Android mounts like /system on a PC?

Tags: linux, mount, file-management, partitions

I know that AndroidCommander works but its [site](http://androidcommander.com) is offline so I can only download version for windoze.

I **ALSO** want to do this if possible the *other way round* **too** (access PC files in Android not only Android files from PC)

How else can I do this?

Comment: I've Galaxy S2 with newest Cyanogenmod (Android **4.4.4**) and PC with Lubuntu 14.04/14.10

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by [edit]ing it. That makes it easier for new visitors to see all the relevant details.

Comment: Which way round are you trying to go? The title sounds like you want to use the PC to see the Android files, but the body says the opposite "access PC files in Android".

Comment: @DanHulme if possible **too** "access PC files in Android"

Comment: Those are completely different questions. This site works best if you ask one question at a time.

Comment: @DanHulme Why is that? Also the questions are almost the same but *other way round*

Also I edited so you can understand better.

Comment: @DanHulme **Both** ways round preferably but the first way (view Android files on PC) is more important

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/q/110362/96277

Answer (score 0):

[ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) has this feature.

On the side Navigation bar you have the options that includes Favorites, Local, Library, and Networks.  Expand the Network tab and click LAN.  You'll see your LAN resources the same way you see them in Windows.

Click on the computer/share you want to browse.  You'll have the option to see the items as icons or detailed listings.

---

**Browsing Android Files from the Windows PC**

To browse the items on the android from the PC, run an FTP server app on the android (There are many such as: [FTP Server Ultimate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.ftpserverultimate)).

On Windows Explorer you can type the full ftp link server name in the Explorer address bar to browse the files and folders just like the other local files and folders on Windows.

You can also type the command "explorer [ftp link]" in Windows 7 Search field to bring up the folders.

Ftp Link Example:

```
explorer ftp://192.168.1.4:2121
```

The numbers after the colon is the port.  2121 is the default port used by most of the android ftp server apps.

Comment: @L-D-James Thank You I should try this if there is no way to do this via usb, meanwhile I'm still looking for it.