# Mount /system and /data partition of an android phone in Windows/Linux

Tags: adb, linux, windows, partitions, system

How can I mount the `/system` and `/data` partition of an Android Phone via USB on a computer? It will need to work with Windows and Linux. I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 with CyanogenMod 12 and working ADB.

PS: I want to have it mounted in a file manager and not in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method that I'm aware of which uses FTP on Android and a tool/software on Linux/Windows. I recently tested this method and it worked well.

- Host an FTP server on your Android phone. (There are answers for it on this site; you may use search option.)
- On GNU/Linux, download **curlftpfs** and issue the command:

  ```
  curlftpfs ftp_server_url directory_path
  ```

  where, ftp_server_url -> the URL of your FTP server, directory_path -> the directory in your PC where you want to mount this server
- On Windows, I've heard that [NetDrive](http://www.netdrive.net/) can mount an FTP server on Windows. I haven't used it but got to know this from a ServerFault answer.
- For Windows, if FTP doesn't work then host a WebDAV server on Android and mount it on Windows by using Windows native **Map network drive** feature.

Whether you would be able to write into `/system` and `/data` isn't my business here since you've not explicitly mentioned it, but my answer will definitely do the thins you asked in the question. :)

(Kindly let me know any fault in my answer rather than downvoting it, if you may. :) )